# Finding a file's directory address on a Mac

Tags: python, macos

I am working with a Macbook programming python. What I want to know is how I can access certain files using Python's file functions. A google search failed me.

For example, Windows would be something like this:

```
f = open(r'C:\text\somefile.txt')
```

How would I access something from a folder saved on the Desktop of a Mac?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The desktop is just a subdirectory of the user’s home directory. Because the latter is not fixed, use something like `os.path.expanduser` to keep the code generic. For example, to read a file called `somefile.txt` that resides on the desktop, use

```
import os
f = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/somefile.txt"))
```

If you want this to be portable across operating systems, you have to find out where the desktop directory is located on each system separately.

Comment: _"If you want this to be portable across operating systems"_ ... you have also to correct the path separators, for example from '/' to '\' if you go to Windows. See my answer.

Comment: Alternatively, if you use [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) rather than `os.path`, you can "blindly" use forward-slashes without it being bad practice.

Answer (score 12):

```
f = open (r"/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/somedir/somefile.txt")
```

or even better

```
import os
f = open (os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/somedir/somefile.txt"))
```

Because on bash (the default shell on Mac Os X) `~/` represents the user's home directory.

Comment: “Because on *nix systems `~/` represents the user's home directory.”—This is wrong, it's only a convention used by popular shells such as bash. Trying to open `~/somefile.txt` will look for a directory called `~` inside the current directory.

Comment: It's not corrected—`open` never expands `~`, and it never uses a shell. Try `open("~/somefile.txt", "w")`—it will fail to create the file unless you have a directory named `~`.

Comment: corrected, but now my answer is almost identical to yours :-(

Answer (score 2):

You're working on a *Mac* so paths like `"a/b/c.text"` are fine, but if you use *Windows* in the future, you'll have to change all the `'/'` to `'\'`. If you want to be more portable and platform-agnostic from the beginning, you better use the `os.path.join` operator:

```
import os

desktop = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop")
filePath = os.path.join(desktop, "somefile.txt")

f = open(filePath)
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is still an issue, I had the same problem and called Apple.  I learned that the file I'd created was saved on iCloud.  The Apple guy told me to save the file locally.  I did that and the problem was solved.