# How do I create a file path on a Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I'm working an OS X platform with Python 3 and I'm not quite sure how to create file paths that link into directories. I know that on the Windows platform it would look something like

```
import os
path = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\<directory name>'
os.mkdir(path)
file = open(path + '\\<file name>.txt', w)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding a file's directory address on a Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324486/finding-a-files-directory-address-on-a-mac)

Comment: It's close, but I'm creating the directory. Does `os.mkdir()` work the same in OSX as in windows? If

Comment: This one should help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-and-create-it-if-necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-and-create-it-if-necessary) using os.makedirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths on OSX use the forward slash (which you can also use on windows). Other than that, the only difference is that OSX (and most other non-windows OS's) don't have drive letters.

The root of any OSX system is "/", everything else is below that. So, for example, your home directory is likely "/Users/myusername". OSX paths are case-insensitive, but case-preserving. That means that "/users/myusername" and "/Users/myusername" go to the same place. If the directory is created with capital letters, the capital letters is what will show with `ls`, in the finder, etc.

`os.mkdir` works the same way on all platforms, assuming you give a valid path.